# jQuery Datatable search option ( alphabetical )

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use jQuery Datatables Plugin.
When I type a in search box Datatables filters all data in table contains a letter
But I want to search (alphabetical ) like this 
when I type 'a' just filters all data starts with 'a'

Comment: turn it around like this `"a%"`?

Comment: @red-X I use client side data filtering like this : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try then:

```
oTable.fnFilter( '^a.*', yourColumn, true );
```

`'^a.*'` the regex searching for, replace the a with your filter

`yourColumn` speaks for itself

`true` needed to treat the first string as a regex, check the [api](http://datatables.net/api)

Comment: That should work for what he is requesting. @shaahin, as a heads-up though, you might have to expand that fnFilter function further... Check out the API: http://datatables.net/api. The fourth optional parameter, "Smart Filtering", has the tendency to conflict if your search terms are RegEx's. It's true by default, you might have to set it false. Also, "yourColumn" will be null if you want the filter to use all columns.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the DataTables initialization and customize how the filtering works. Check the link below, same exact situation. You'll need to grab the data from the filter box and filter on a stricter RegEx focusing on the beginning of the data in the cells.

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/255/customising-the-way-the-filter-works/p1